# Show a message on screen if a specific folder is empty Applescripts

Tags: macos, applescript

I have a system which move files across the network to my MAC computer (CSV File), that file is necessary for me to feed a local system, but sometimes people forget sending it or producing it, so I need to show an error message in my computer that says "Careful, there is not a file in your folder"

A POP UP would be good to have, this script should run every 2 seconds, it should show a button to close the message.

Any ideas on how to do this using applescripts? anyone have example code?

Comment: You want want a pop up showing every two seconds, wouldn't that get annoying?

Comment: Well, the POP UP should stay there till press OK, if is there will not create a new one. That CSV file is very important.

Comment: How are you opening the file? I would think a safe-guard against allowing it to open if it doesn't exist might be a better approach.

Comment: That File is a CSV file which is used by my system to populate data, the process of populating the data is made manually once in the system, but before that to happen, I should see a message saying "Hey there is not data to use" or similar, this is because some people use the system and forget to populate the data into it (they can still see the data ON screen from old imports, so they believe that there is a file in there, but sometimes there is not)

Comment: Are you wanting the AppleScript to open when the system is turned on, or something you launch then leave running?

Comment: I have a system which opens the file and read the content, it populate a screen and then it deletes the file.
If my understanding is right, you want to know what triggers that CSV to be read. For this, I have written a .APP which start the Recording and other which STOP the recording, it could be a good idea to put a line on that RECORD .APP so it will check for the file first, if file is there, it will continue, if CSV file is not there, it will show POP UP.

Comment: I think that should be the process, thanks for your analysis. 
Do you know the code for checking files, and if doesn't find the file to show the POP UP?
So I can add it to the RECORD.APP

Comment: Yes, it's pretty simple - I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something such as this might be what you are looking for:

```
set POSIXpath to "/path/of/file"
set POSIXfile to POSIXpath & "file.csv"
set theAlias to POSIX file POSIXfile

tell application "Finder"
    repeat
        --The next line is optional
        if exists process "Application of CSV file" then
            if not (exists theAlias) then
                --display alert
                display alert "Warning: the file does not exist"
            end if
        end if
        delay 5
    end repeat
end tell
```

The optional line I included can be made to check for the process of whatever application you are using the file with. So for example:

```
    if exists process "Numbers" then
```

This checks first to see if the application "Numbers" was currently running. If you choose not to check the application process remove that line and one `end if` statement.

Comment: That code work fine for me, I have created a new APP with that and it's checking now for the file when my recording APP is running, it's also showing that the file is not there.
It worked! 
Thanks again.